# Extract value for a key in a key/pair string

Tags: bash

I have key value pairs in a string like this:

```
key1   =   "value1"
key2   =   "value2"
key3   =   "value3"
```

In a bash script, I need to extract the value of one of the keys like for `key2`, I should get `value2`, not in quote.

My bash script needs to work in both Redhat and Ubuntu Linux hosts.

What would be the easiest and most reliable way of doing this?

I tried something like this **simplified** script:

```
pattern='key2\s*=\s*\"(.*?)\".*$'
if [[ "$content" =~ $pattern ]]
then
  key2="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  echo "key2: $key2"
else
  echo 'not found'
fi
```

But it does not work consistently.

Any better/easier/more reliable way of doing this?

Comment: Have you set `shopt -s extglob`?

Comment: `does not work consistently` What do you mean by "consistently"? `I tried something like this simplified script` What is `content` in your script? Are the key value pairs stored in a file? or does `content` contain the whole string? Could you post `declare -p content` output?

Comment: @AllanXu: Please provide a concrete value for which your program does not work.

Comment: @user1934428,   the answer is: avoid non-greedy match in bash at all cost. I have it working now.

Comment: @KamilCuk, see my comment above

Comment: This answer solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981398/non-greedy-text-matching-and-extrapolating-in-bash

Answer (score 2):

To separate the `key` and `value` from your `$content` variable, you can use:

```
[[ $content =~ (^[^ ]+)[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*[[:punct:]](.*)[[:punct:]]$ ]]
```

That will properly populate the `BASH_REMATCH` array with both values where your `key` is in `BASH_REMATCH[1]` and the `value` in `BASH_REMATCH[2]`.

**Explanation**

In bash the `[[...]]` treats what appears on the right side of `=~` as an extended regular expression and matched according to [man 3 regex](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regex.3.html). See [man 1 bash](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) under the section heading for `[[ expression ]]` (4th paragraph). Sub-expressions in parenthesis `(..)` are saved in the array variable `BASH_REMATCH` with `BASH_REMATCH[0]` containing the entire portion of the string (your `$content`) and each remaining elements containing the sub-expressions enclosed in `(..)` in the order the parenthesis appear in the regex.

The Regular Expression `(^[^ ]+)[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*[[:punct:]](.*)[[:punct:]]$` is explained as:

- `(^[^ ]+)` - `'^'` anchored at the beginning of the line, `[^ ]+` match one or more characters that are not a space. Since this sub-expression is enclosed in `(..)` it will be saved as `BASH_REMATCH[1]`, followed by;
- `[[:blank:]]*` - zero or more whitespace characters, followed by;
- `=` - an equal sign, followed by;
- `[[:blank:]]*` - zero or more whitespace characters, followed by;
- `[[:punct:]]` - a punctuation character (matching the `'"'`, which avoids caveats associated with using quotes within the regex), followed by the sub-expression;
- `(.*)` - zero or more characters (the rest of the characters), and since it is a sub-expression in `(..)` it the characters will be stored in `BASH_REMATCH[2]`, followed by;
- `[[:punct:]]` - a punctuation character (matching the `'"'` ... ditto), at the;
- `$` - end of line anchor.

So if you match what your `key` and `value` input lines separated by an `=` sign, it will separate the `key` and `value` into the array `BASH_REMATCH` as you wanted.

Comment: I am not familiar with this syntax of regex. Can you give me the name, so I can serach and learn?

Comment: I tested and I had the same issue. I think end of line $ is confused with files created in diffrent platforms (win, linux, mac)

this solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981398/non-greedy-text-matching-and-extrapolating-in-bash

Comment: @AllanXu I have updated and added the full explanation. There is more than one way to write the regular expression. (it just makes it a bit longer)

Answer (score 1):

Bash supports `BRE` only and you cannot use `\s` and `.*?`.
As an alternative, please try:

```
while IFS= read -r content; do
#   pattern='key2\s*=\s*\"(.*)\".*$'
    pattern='key2[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*"([^"]*)"'
    if [[ $content =~ $pattern ]]
    then
        key2="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        echo "key2: $key2"
        (( found++ ))
    fi
done < input-file.txt

if (( found == 0 )); then
    echo "not found"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

What you start talking about key-value pairs, it is best to use an associative array:

```
declare -A map
```

Now looking at your lines, they look like `key = "value"` where we assume that:

- `value` is always encapsulated by double quotes, but also could contain a quote
- an unknown number of white spaces is before and/or after the equal sign.

So assuming we have a variable `line` which contains `key = "value"`, the following operations will extract that value:

```
key="${line%%=*}"; key="${key// /}"
value="${line#*=}"; value="${value#*\042}"; value="${value%\042*}"
IFS=" \t=" read -r value _ <<<"$line"
```

This allows us now to have something like:

```
declare -A map
while read -r line; do
  key="${line%%=*}"; key="${key// /}"
  value="${line#*=}"; value="${value#*\042}"; value="${value%\042*}"
  map["$key"]="$value"
done <inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
awk -v key="key2" '$1 == key { gsub("\"","",$3);print $3 }' <<< "$string"
```

Reading the output of the variable called string, pass the required key in as a variable called key and then if the first space delimited field is equal to the key, remove the quotes from the third field with the gsub function and print.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after spending so many hours, this is how I solved the problem:

If you don't know where your script will run and what type of file (win/mac/linux) are you reading:

1. Try to avoid non-greedy macth in linux bash instead of tweaking diffrent switches.
2. don't trus end of line match $ when you might get data from windows or mac

This post solved my problem: [Non greedy text matching and extrapolating in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981398/non-greedy-text-matching-and-extrapolating-in-bash)

This pattern works for me in may linux environments and all type of end of lines:

`pattern='key2\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"'`

The value is in `BASH_REMATCH[1]`